# How do I pass variables from ruby to sh command

Tags: ruby, rake, sh

I have a rake task that runs, quite a lot of code. At the end, I need to use sftp and ssh to do some stuff. At the moment I'm unable to automate it. Is there a way to pass to stdout?

This seems like a simple question but I can't find the answer anywhere

```
#some ruby code
#more ruby code
sh "sftp myuser@hots" #this opens the sftp console
sh "put file" #this doesn't get run until sftp is exited
sh "put another_file" #neither does this

#more ruby code
sh "ssh host" # opens the ssh console
sh "some_action_on_host" # this doesn't get run until ssh is exited
```

I know there will be ways of doing sftp and ssh using ruby but ideally I just want to be able to pipe variables and commands into the console

Comment: Trying to drive SSH sessions via the command-line is more work than using the [Net::SSH](http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v2/api/index.html) module because of the interactive nature of terminals and command-lines, unless you are sending a single command at a time. Net::SSH gives you quite a bit of control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to run sftp and send a series of commands to it? How about something like:

```
sftp = IO.popen("sftp myuser@hots", "w+")
sftp << "put file\n"
sftp << "put another file\n"
sftp.flush # make sure to include this
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ruby, then you may want to enclose your shell commands into ` (backtick characters). This string will be passed to Kernel.` method. This method execute the text as an OS shell command and returns the command's output as a string, e.g.:

```
`ls`
```

Alternative syntax to ` is `%x[]`. This way you can write any bash script:

```
%x[sftp myuser@hots <<COMMAND
  put #{file}
  quit
COMMAND]
```

Please note that this syntax support ruby expressions interpolation using `#{...}` syntax (similar to double-quoted string literals).